# Inlined icons in a button arent centered when i change the width and height of the button to small numbers

Tags: html, css

I have buttons which follow the following structure:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm"(click)="doSomething()">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

They look like this:

[image: First picture]

I can change the height and width of the buttons and the inline icons will stay centered:

```
.btn.btn-dark.btn-sm {
    height: 80px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

[image]

But then when im making them smaller for mobile, all of the sudden, the inlined icons stop being centered after i fall below a certain width/height:

```
@media (max-width: 690px){
.btn.btn-dark.btn-sm {
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
  }
}
```

[image: third]

Why do they stop being centered on small width/height? How would i fix it? I tried alligning them to the center etc, but didnt find a working solution yet.

Comment: check your padding of the button or margin of the icon

Comment: Show us more css code. For instance, what is CSS style for the icons?

Comment: also, 10px is ridiculously small, maybe start with trying not to break it with such small sizes

Comment: Why not just do it like this, I think this is the smallest you can make it without overriding too much bootstrap https://jsfiddle.net/rjc5phe0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the button may have some padding that interferes when too small. Try this snippet

```css
.btn.btn-dark.btn-sm {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" (click)="doSomething()">
  <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Ye, my bad. I missed it. The `.btn-sm` buttons have a little bit of padding which isnt visual to the eye unless the buttons become really small. Setting the padding to zero and increasing the height/width slightly fixes it.

Comment: I don't think this will work with the OP setting the original width and height, then using `@media`